# How to use Matchers with doReturn in Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I want to use doReturn to not call the actual method but only return a value using Matchers, I've done the following snippet:

```
Sender sender = Mockito.spy(new Sender());
Mockito.doReturn(response)
    .when(sender)
    .callRestClient(
        Mockito.anyString(),
        Mockito.anyString(),
        Mockito.anyString(),
        Mockito.anyString());
```

but when the  tests run with actual values for callRestClient, the method  is actually called ( which I would expect not ).
in this case Sender is an Spy object

Comment: Which method is called?

Comment: callRestClient(..)

Comment: Is sender mock object or spy on real object?

Comment: Hi Kaushal , it is Spy

Comment: Please add the whole minimal code how you create the mock including any creation of Spy and other relevant stuff to help others to reproduce.

Comment: Can you add : callRestClient method and code part of your test class where you call this method ?

Comment: Maybe you should add yet an example of actual test data that fails. And your mockito version.

Comment: Code snippet looks okay and it works fine when tried. Check if any other overload of callRestClient. You might be mocking one overload while code is calling another overload.

Comment: This code looks correct, but Mockito may not be able to intercept the call unless Sender is public and non-final and callRestClient is public, non-static, and non-final. (Protected methods package-private classes/methods might still work, but I know of at least one bug about that in previous versions of Mockito.) Can you check whether those factors are involved?

Comment: what if callRestClient  is protected, declared in the class beig tested ? I will try  , sender is default and is declared in the Test class

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no overloading

Answer (score 0):

Please create a senderMock using and change the statement to following

```
@MockBean Sender senderMock

Mockito.when(senderMock.callRestClient(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(response);
```

Comment: I need a spy in the real object ,If I make what you suggest, the method will be called, which is what I want to avoid. thanks.

Comment: Don't use `@MockBean`, as this implies the SpringRunner. The question is about Mockito. Mockito uses the `@Mock` annotation